# Does Clipping Work in Blender 2.9?

Tags: rendering

From the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html), it appears that when I create a `view > render regions > clipping region` (<kbd>CMD + B</kbd>), only the selection within the clipping should be visible, however:

[image: clipping example]

I have tried different views. Also checked to see if, for example, Transform, would only with within the "clip", and that doesn't happen either. Rendering also isn't limited to what's inside the clipping area.

So am expecting I am missing a step or otherwise misunderstanding either:

- what is supposed to happen
- how it's supposed to work
- how to achieve it

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  your screen shot, you enabled ["render region"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region) rather than clipping region. Not sure what's the correct key bind in Mac OS, but in windows, it's <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> (Which might be eq to <kbd>Cmd + B</kbd> in common translation).

Please look at the menu again, it said <kbd>Alt + B</kbd> to create clipping region, as the following picture show. Red dashed line is for render region, and it's separated from clipping region.

[image]

Remember, It is "clipped", not hidden. It should only be working in *Solid* or *Wired Frame* view mode. On the other hand, render region only works during rendering in Cycles.

Comment: Isn't the stuff outside of the clipping region supposed to be hidden, though?

Comment: Hey, it's working now, as I had expected, in a fresh file. Does it only work in certain views?

Comment: It is 'Clipped', not hidden. It should only working in "bench mark" view mode (solid, wired frame). On the other hand, render region only work in 'render' (Cycles)

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer, adding that last comment.